# Trace class operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $A\in B(H)$ and $\sum_{E}|\langle A e,e\rangle|< \infty$ for every orthonormal basis $E$. Show that $A$ is a trace class (means $\sum_E \langle |A|e,e\rangle < \infty$). I can not prove it. Please give me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: It was answered here a long time ago. You search along the site.

Comment: @userNaN : I could not find it. If it's possible, please answer it again.

Comment: you should ask [Martin Argerami](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/22857/martin-argerami). His a main specialist on operator algebras here.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : If possible, please give me a hint about this question.

Comment: @niki: AFAIK, you cannot ping people that have not contributed to the thread.

Comment: @niki: Here you can find a proof: [Trace Class](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/208508/79762)