# Are autocovariance operators trace class?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, covariance

> Suppose that $\{X_k\}_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ is a weakly stationary sequence of random elements with values in a complex separable Hilbert space $\mathbb H$ and let us define the sequence of autocovariance operators by setting
>   $$
> C_t(h)=\operatorname E[\langle h,X_0\rangle X_t]
> $$
>   for each $t\in\mathbb Z$ and $h\in\mathbb H$. Are the autocovariance operators $C_t$ [trace class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class) for each $t\in\mathbb Z$? If they are, how can we prove that?

The autocovariance operators $C_t$ are not necessarily self-adjoint for $t\ne0$, nor are they necessarily non-negative definite for $t\ne0$. So it seems that we cannot determine if they are trace class by checking the convergence of the series $\sum_{n\ge1}\langle C_te_n,e_n\rangle$ for some orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n\ge1}$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208508/a-characterization-of-trace-class-operators?rq=1)). However, we have that $\sum_{n\ge1}\langle C_te_n,e_n\rangle=\operatorname E\langle X_t,X_0\rangle$ and the right side of the equality is finite so the series on the left side converges.

Any help is much appreciated!